# Suppose $A x^4 + B y^4 + (C+D) x^2 y^2 < 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0) \}$. Then what?

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Let $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$A x^4 + B y^4 + (C+D) x^2 y^2 < 0$$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0) \}$.

> Does this imply that $$A+B + \sqrt{ (A-B)^2 + (C+D)^2 } <0?$$

If $x =1, y=0$, we see that $A<0$. If $x=0,y=1$, we see that $B<0$.

Comment: That's equivalent to asking for $A t^2 + (C+D) t + B < 0$ on $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: I think it implies:  either $A<0, ~ B < 0, ~A+B + \sqrt{ (A-B)^2 + (C+D)^2 } <0, ~ C + D > 0$, or $A < 0, ~ B < 0, ~ C + D \le 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no, it does not imply that. Consider:

$$\begin{align}
-(x^2+y^2)(x^2+2y^2)&<0\\
-x^4-2y^4+(-2-1)x^2y^2&<0
\end{align}$$

So the given condition with $A=D=-1$, $B=C=-2$. Then

$$A+B + \sqrt{ (A-B)^2 + (C+D)^2 } = -3 + \sqrt{ 10 } >0$$

---

As noted in a comment and another posted answer, the desired result is equivalent to a certain discriminant being negative. In other words, a certain quadratic polynomial having no real roots. It's easy to show that quadratic has no *positive* roots, but it could have negative ones. To build the example, I took $$(t+1)(t+2)$$ with two negative roots and grew it into $$-\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(x^2+2y^2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that:
$$(A+B)^2>(A-B)^2+(C+D)^2$$ or
$$4AB>(C+D)^2,$$ which is $\Delta<0$.

What do you think now?

Comment: Got it, thanks!